# Не работает "! + tab" в vs code (remote-ssh) для HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

У меня на mac os x установлено VS Code. Я через плагин для vs code remote-ssh подключаюсь к linux debian 11 сервер и разрабатываю django приложение. В локальном vs code автоматически заполнение (! + tab) html структуру работает, а на удаленном сервер debian 11 не работает. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что расширение "Emmet" установлено на удаленном сервере:
Убедитесь, что Emmet включен:
Убедитесь, что Emmet правильно настроен для HTML:
Если автоматическое заполнение не работает, возможно, сокращения по умолчанию не сконфигурированы для HTML. В этом случае, добавьте следующий код в пользовательские настройки (User Settings) VS Code:

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"html": "html"
},